Bacula not open 9102 port, but no errors
I would appreciate a lot if anyone with knowledge can help me this. It is for a student project.
I need help with bacula server, in a run job i'm receiving this message :"waiting for Client VMSRV-WEB-100-01-fd to connect to Storage"
It seems that the client cant connect with the storage
I did a telnet from client to server (where is the storage) and it is refusing the connection.
    root@VMSRV-WEB-100-01:/etc/bacula# telnet 10.1.10.122 9102
Trying 10.1.10.122...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

The unique process working with this port is bacula
root@VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01:/home/sirs# lsof -i :9102
COMMAND      PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bacula-fd  67468   root    3u  IPv4 312136      0t0  TCP localhost:bacula-fd (LISTEN)
bacula-di 112043 bacula    9u  IPv4 627589      0t0  TCP VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01:54034->VMSRV-WEB-100-01:bacula-fd (ESTABLISHED)

In the client works fine.
This is my bacula-dir.conf
root@VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01:/home/sirs# cat /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf
Director {
  Name = "VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01-dir"
  Messages = Daemon
  DirAddress = 0.0.0.0
  QueryFile = "/etc/bacula/scripts/query.sql"
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"
  PidDirectory = "/run/bacula"
  MaximumConcurrentJobs = 1
  Password = "3ul_s4o9kaBF_fT3f6OCjtlxdAIxxJoIL"
}
Client {
  Name = "VMSRV-WEB-100-01-fd"
  Address = 10.1.10.121
  FdPort = 9102
  Password = "3ul_s4o9kaBF_fT3f6OCjtlxdAIxxJoIL"
  FdStorageAddress = 0.0.0.0
  Catalog = "MyCatalog"
  FileRetention = 5184000
  JobRetention = 15552000
  AutoPrune = yes
}

bacula-sd.conf
root@VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01:/home/sirs# cat /etc/bacula/bacula-sd.conf

Director {
  Name = "VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01-dir"
  Password = "$51R5admin2024"
  #Password = "3ul_s4o9kaBF_fT3f6OCjtlxdAIxxJoIL"
}
Director {
  Name = "VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01-mon"
  Password = "_Pyrf6xzob1ZR8OgecKzrsAdT58QiLJfv"
  Monitor = yes
}
Storage {
  Name = "BackupLocal"
  SdAddress = 0.0.0.0
  WorkingDirectory = "/bacula/backup"
  PidDirectory = "/run/bacula"
  MaximumConcurrentJobs = 20
}
Device {
  Name = "DeviceWebServer"
  MediaType = "TypeWebServer"
  DeviceType = "File"
  ArchiveDevice = "/bacula/backup/BackupWebServer"
  RemovableMedia = no
  RandomAccess = yes
  AutomaticMount = yes
  LabelMedia = yes
  AlwaysOpen = yes
  MaximumConcurrentJobs = 20
}
Messages {
  Name = "Standard"
  Director = VMSRV-BACKUP-100-01-dir = All, !Debug, !Saved
}

